# how to run and debug app script project on eclipse?

Tags: debugging, google-apps-script, eclipse-plugin

I just import a Google App Script project and write some js code and I want to test it like in the online Google Console, but I just cant find how? do i need to set up a Google Server or something? or I just can't debug on my local machine? (that will be sad)

Comment: I had and have the same problem and asked a similar question before see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978419/how-to-run-gas-from-eclipse-4-3 If anyone knows a better development environment I'll be happy to use!